# How to get attribute inside square brackets with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, bbcode

I want to get the value of the background attribute (background.jpg) inside square bracket like BBCode editor's and I tried this regexp

```
\[(\w+)[^\]]*](.*?)\[\/\1]/g
```

but it didn't work.

```
[code background="background.jpg"] Here some text [/code]
```

Comment: The regexp match "code" and "Here some text" but I want it to match the value inside background attribute which is "background.jpg".
[link](http://regex101.com/r/rV2aA1/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below regex and get the value of `background` attribute from group index 2.

```
\[(\w+)\s\S+?="([^\]"]*)"](.*?)\[\/\1]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/7)

Comment: Thank you so much this regexp worked great for me.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdh1L8to/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
\[(\w+)[^\]]*?background="([^"]+)"[^\]]*\](.*?)\[\/\1]
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/8